# I want to create an array of non-overlapping random numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create an array of non-overlapping random numbers with a length of 20.

However, when executed, the array is not complete and sometimes an error message "Too many re-renders" appears.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Ques = () => {

  const [randArr, setRandArr]  = useState([]);
  const [randNum, setRandNum] = useState(0);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (19-0));

  if(randArr.length !== 20 && randArr.includes(randNum) === true){
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (19-0));
    setRandNum(rand)
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    setRandNum(rand);
    setRandArr([...randArr, randNum]);
    console.log("randNum : ", randNum);
    console.log("randArr : ", randArr);  
  },[rand]);


  
  return (
    <div>
      <button>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Ques;
```

Comment: You're making a new random number every time the function is called, so it's always different and the useEffect runs. Inside your useEffect you mutate state, which calls the function again, and this causes an infinite loop that React prevents and results in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, you are declaring a new `rand` value each render cycle and using it as a dependency for an `useEffect` hook which then also enqueues a state update and triggers a rerender... repeat ad nauseam.

Instead of trying to iterate and populate an array with "random" numbers by "guessing" if they've already been selected, it'd be better to start with an array of `[1..20]` and "shuffle" it.

Example:

```js
const res = Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => i + 1).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
console.log(res.join(","));
```

You can just initialize your state to this value. No need for any loops and `useEffect` hooks.

```
const [randArr, setRandArr] = useState(
  Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => i + 1).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [random, setRandom] = useState([]);

  const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (19 - 0));

  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      arr.push(getRandom());
    }
    setRandom(arr);
    console.log(arr);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{random.join(",")}</div>
      <button>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for contributing an answer to SO. Generally, code-only answers should be avoided, so would you please add an explanation and necessary information?